# Vue JS - instead of one click, the component is shown on double click

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events, vuejs2

I have four images, when the mouse cursor is hovering over them, a certain component is displayed, I applied two `mouseover` and `onclick` events for these images, I applied `onclick` so that when the screen reaches the mobile version, that is, below 568 pixels, when the image is clicked, a certain component is displayed, and when you clicked on this picture again, a certain component was hidden, It looks like this

```
<img v-on:click="isHidden = !isHidden" :src="item.img" alt="Show">
```

The problem is that when I try to open a picture in the mobile version, I need to double-click on the picture so that the component is displayed instead of one, I assume that this problem is due to the fact that I accept two events for them mousover and onclick, but how can I get rid of this Problems?

```
<div v-for="(girl, index) in sectionGirlsList" v-bind:key="index">

  <div @mouseover="mouseOver(girl, hover = true)">
    <div>
        <img v-on:click="isHidden = !isHidden" :src="girl.girlImg" alt="Show">
    </div>

    <div v-if="selected == girl && !isHidden" class="next-to-description">
      <div v-for="(enjoy, index) in sectionGirlsList" :key="index">
    
            <component v-show="enjoy.hovered" v-bind:is="enjoy.componentName">
            </component>
       
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>


mouseOver: function (girl) {
  this.sectionGirlsList.forEach((girl) => (girl.hovered = false));
  this.isHidden = false;
  girl.hovered = true;
  this.selected = girl;
},

mouseout: function (girl) {
  this.selected = null
  girl.hovered = false;
},
```

I would like to briefly explain the problem once again, when you select the mobile version in the browser console, you need to click on the picture twice to display the component instead of one, you can also see the [full code in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-ritchie-kty9h)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no persistence cursor on mobile phone, you need to click on an element to trigger hover or mouse in and out event; and It causes click event to be triggered too. just as you said.
therefore you need to handle things in click event and its callback function, which here is named controller.
'clicked' variable is used for store if the client clicks the same element for second time to collapse images or not.
if client clicks the same element for collapsing it will be false, if user clicks another element while former element is still selected it will be true. if anything were selected, and then a client selects an element, it will be true.

you can see it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-chatelet-14j1x?file=/src/components/GirlsSectionList.vue:8592-8612)

```
data(){
  return{
    clicked:false,
  }
},
    
methods:{
    mouseOver: function (girl) {
          this.show(girl);
          this.clicked = false;
        },
    
        mouseout: function (girl) {
          this.hide(girl);
          this.clicked = true;
        },
        show:function(girl){
          this.sectionGirlsList.forEach((girl) => (girl.hovered = false));
          this.isHidden = false;
          girl.hovered = true;
          this.selected = girl;
          
        },
        hide:function(girl){
          this.selected = null;
          girl.hovered = false;
          
        },
        controller: function(girl){
          if(this.clicked){
            if(this.selected === girl){
              this.hide(girl);
              this.clicked = false;
            }
            else{
              this.show(girl);
              this.clicked = true;
            }
          }
          else{
            this.show(girl);
            this.clicked = true;
          }
          
        },
}
```

I myself would use window object and innerWidth property to determine the width of screen and use click event for mobile and hover event for non-mobile screen.